# Altium BOM puts different components into same excel row

Tags: altium, bom

When I generate the BOM in my Altium project, the programm puts for no obvious reason two different kind os resistors and a DC Connector into one row in my BOM.
The components have completetly different parmeters and i seem to not find the solution to this on the Altium website.

The following Components were in one row:

- R1, R3, and R4 are 4k7 Resistors
- R2 is a 1k Resistors
- X7 is a DC Power Jack

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you clarify "been on"? I researched the problem, I didn't find any explanation on the Altium website, and then I came here and to asked my fellow Engineers

Comment: Been on = visited.

Comment: As I mentioned: **The Altium Website**. I didn't find anything on other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altium lets you choose which columns are used to group components. Check your BOM export settings.

[image]

Comment: Exactly right. I generally group mine by part number and a custom parameter called notes, which is where I specify if the part is DNP

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I updated my post. I was able to generate a sorted BOM but my active BOM seems empty. Do you possibly know the reason why?

Comment: ActiveBOM is a complete tool in itself, and is different from your original question. What do you have in the "Columns" tab? I have not had the opportunity to work much with ActiveBOMs so far, so I suggest exploring the tool (maybe watch some tutorials) and see what you can find

Comment: @Lyoner I agree with DerStrom8 here. If the original question has been answered, please accept. I haven't used ActiveBOM either, so I'm not in a position to answer that part at the moment.

Comment: ok, thank you for your advice so far! I will change it back and mark it done :)